# Context in GPS Plugin

Tags: gnat-gps

I created a button in the toolbar using

```
GPS.Toolbar().append(button)
```

In the `On_Click` function of the button I want it to print the current file's name.

I wrote `print GPS.Current_Context().file()`
But it does'nt work and give me the error : `Current_Context has no attribute file`

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EditorBuffer` to get the current view's name:

```
EditorBuffer.get().current_view().title()
```

This will give you the title of the current editor tab, which is the name of the edited file.